# Angular: my isolated attribute not binding in simple directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using [this tutorial](http://seanhess.github.io/2013/10/14/angularjs-directive-design.html) to understand how to display an image using directives with an isolate scope. What am i missing to get the attribute to bind? In my ide, I can output the image but the directive is not working. The fiddle displays nothing :-(

Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/gogirl/Stm3j/

This is outputted in my program:

```
 output:{{photo.url}}
<img ng-src='http://www.w3schools.com/js/pic_bulboff.gif' />
```

This is not outputted:

```
 <my-d photo-src={{photo.url}} ></my-d>
```

Comment: Chen-Tsu: the reason I believe that no controller is needed is that there is no change in state. The init directive is enough to pass on the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You have residual data in your jsfiddle configuration**

### Here is what I did to make it work

1. Remove the external resources because you use angular 1.0.1 with angular 1.2.1
2. Remove in options panel the body tag `myModule`
3. Remove the call of the undefined variable `app` and query it with `angular.module`

### [jsfiddle updated here](http://jsfiddle.net/Stm3j/3/)

```
// My Main Application File
angular.module('myApp', ['myDirectives']);

// My Directives File
angular.module('myDirectives', []);

// Controller One File
angular.module('myDirectives', []).directive('myD', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<figure> <img ng-src="{{photoSrc}}"/> </figure>',
        replace: true,
        // pass these two names from attrs into the template scope
        scope: {
            photoSrc: '@'
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Merci Aduch. As you can see our answers crossed but am so happy that I can use chaining again.

Comment: Yes it is sometimes hard to work on several versions of a configuration, step back the go forth again leaving some traces ;)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Working Examle]

All is working fine now when i switched the original module chaining method with the global app method:

```
   var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
       app.directive('myD', function() {
           return {
               restrict: 'E',
               template: '<figure> <img ng-src="{{photoSrc}}"/> </figure>',
               replace: true,
               // pass this name from attrs into the template scope
               scope: {
                   photoSrc: '@'
               }
       }
    });
```

But I wont be a happy camper until I figure out what is wrong with the chaining declaration as it works fine elsewhere. Any takers? Fiddle still not working so i think it may be an issue with it being a fiddle.
EDIT: WORKS fine also with chaining method..One baby step at a time :-)